# What is wrong with assigning values to a WP_List_Table class?

Tags: php, oop, wp-list-table

I was trying to fix a use of the Wordpress list with 4.3 update, when I noticed some odd behavior when subclassing the list class. As a minimal example:

```
class Another_List_Table extends WP_List_Table {

    function __construct($handle) {
        $args = array(
            'plural' => 'things',
            'singular' => 'thing',
        );
        parent::__construct( $args );

        $this->columns = array(
            'yada' => 'yada'
        );
        $this->sortable = array(
            'title' => array('title', false),
            'something' => array( 'something', true )
        );
        $this->default_sort = 'title';
        //You get the picture... set a bunch of instance variables.

        var_dump( $this->sortable );
        var_dump( $this->columns );
        echo 'ANOTHERLIST sort '.( $this->default_sort) . '.!';

    }
}
new Another_List_Table( );
```

Surprisingly, this actually outputs:

null

null

ANOTHERLIST sort .!

What obscure feature/bug of PHP is not letting me set variables on the object, and what would be the purpose of this? This is on Ubuntu 14.04 with PHP 5.5.

Comment: [Magic methods](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php). Check out the source of `WP_List_Table` and you'll see a `__get` and `__set` method, which are altering the default behaviour of interacting with class properties.

Comment: Looks like that's the answer, thanks! I updated docs on http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_List_Table#Methods_and_Properties